# iOS9 Facebook Login canOpenURL error

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, ios9, facebook-ios-sdk

I am having an issue with Facebook SDK 4.6 using iOS9 and Xcode7.

When testing on a device, nothing happens when I click the login button and in the iOS Simulator, I receive an error.

```
2015-10-01 17:12:32.197 TestProject[32112:797172] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:///" - error: "(null)"
```

In my plist file, I have included the following

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
 <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
 <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>

<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>fbauth</string>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
 </array>


<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
<dict>
<key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
<array>
<string>fb{FACEBOOK_APP_ID}</string>
</array>
</dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>{FACEBOOK_APP_ID}</string> 
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>{Your App Name}</string>
```

Comment: My god I hope there's a fix to this soon... It seems like this bug is halting production of every other IOS9 app out there!

Comment: It's a benign error that means the corresponding app isn't installed. You can safely ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

That's just a runtime warning that lets you know that the Application that handles that Scheme is not installed on the phone.

Facebook's docs even have a note about it:

> This is an Xcode warning indicating the the canOpenURL: call returned
>   false. As long as you have configured the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes
>   entry in your plist as described above, you can ignore this warning

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9

Can you share your AppDelegate's code and the code where you are trying to login? Maybe there's something there...